# VBA to get previous working day

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a VBA to automatically populate yesterday's date in a cell, but need assistance as how should get the date as 16th June(Friday) instead of 18th June(which is a Sunday) when I trigger it on Monday.

```
`If .Column <> 11 Or .Row < 1 Then Exit Sub
    If .Value = "Select" Then
        If .Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            .Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = Now - 1
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = Now - 1
            .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy" '<~~ mmm-yy
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = GetMonthWeek(Now - 1)
        End If'
```

Comment: So you understand that `GetMonthWeek` is not a native VBA command or function so that any real attempt at solving your problem would have to know how that was defined (UDF?) in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worksheet functions can easily retrieve the previous Friday whether or not the current day is a Friday.

```
'last Friday regardless
=A2-WEEKDAY(A2, 16)
'last Friday unless a Friday
=A2-WEEKDAY(A2, 16)+(WEEKDAY(A2)=6)*7
```

WEEKDAY and boolean operations are directly transferable to VBA.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there is any inbuilt method for that, but the following logic works:

```
Dim tempDate
tempDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)         'Today's date - 1
While Weekday(tempDate) = 1 Or Weekday(tempDate) = 7     'If tempDate is a Sunday or a Saturday, keep on subtracting one day until we get a weekday
    tempDate = DateAdd("d", -1, tempDate)
Wend
Cells(1, 1).Value = tempDate
```

Try implementing this in your code and let me know if it works. :)